# redefinition of class c++ header files

Tags: c++, file, header

The main class:

```cpp
#include "otherClass.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    a cl;
    return 0;
}
```

The header file:

```cpp
#ifndef OTHERCLASS_H_INCLUDED_
#define OTHERCLASS_H_INCLUDED_

class a {
    int add(int a, int b);
    int subtract(int a, int b);
};

#endif
```

The .cpp class that the header files corresponds to

```cpp
#include "otherClass.h"

class a { 
    int add(int a, int b) {
        return (a + b);
    }
 
    int subtract(int a, int b) {
        return (a - b);
    }
};
```

The error:

> Text.cpp:13: error: ‘cl’ was not declared in this scope
> otherClass.cpp:3: error: redefinition of ‘class a’ otherClass.h:3:
> error: previous definition of ‘class a’

I have two questions: First, before I added a class inside my header file , the file worked fine (just holding functions). Once I added classes, I got the above two errors. Can someone please tell me how to arrange my *header file* to fix these errors? I.e. I want to know how to be able to make a header file for a file that contains a class.

Second, how do I get it so the class is declared within the scope of the main function?

Comment: That way you're simply going to do an invalid redeclaration of your class in the compilation unit, instead of just provide an implementation for `class a`!

Answer (score 5):

This is how you would define the class' member functions in the `.cpp` file:

```
#include "otherClass.h"

int a::add(int a, int b) {
  return (a + b);
}

int a::subtract(int a, int b) {
  return (a - b);
}
```

Note that you have declared the members `private`, so you won't be able to do much with them.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error: redefinition of class / previous definition of class

Comment: @user1930111 The class definition is fine (assuming you want the members to be private). But the include guards should not have leading underscores. Double leading underscores are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: even without those the double underscores (i just edited it), I'm still getting the same errors

Comment: @user1930111 then you have some other problem elsewhere. There is no reason what I posted, together with your class definition, should fail.

Answer (score 2):

Remove

```
class a {
```

and the final

```
};
```

from the .cpp file

(and add a:: to the methods, as per previous answer)